# Possible to animate polygon fill using gganimate in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have county level data recording the year an invasive insect pest was first detected in that county between 2002 and 2018. I created a map using ggplot2 and the maps package that fills the county polygons with a color according to the year the pest was detected. [image]

**Is there a way to use the gganimate package to animate this map with the first frame filling in only polygons with a detection date of 2002, the second frame filling polygons with a detection date of 2003 or earlier (so 2002 and 2003), a third frame for detection dates of 2004 or earlier (2002, 2003, 2004), etc.? **
Clarification: I'd like it so all the county polygons are always visible and filled in with white initially and each frame of the animation adds fills in counties based on the year of detection.

I've tried using the `transition_reveal(data$detect_year)` with the static plot but get an error that "along data must either be integer, numeric, POSIXct, Date, difftime, orhms".

Here's some code for a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
# Reproducible example
set.seed(42)
map_df <- map_data("county") %>% 
   filter(region == "minnesota")
map_df$detection_year <- NA
# Add random detection year to each county
years <- 2002:2006
map_list <- split(map_df, f = map_df$subregion)
map_list <- map(map_list, function(.x) {
   .x$detection_years <- mutate(.x, detection_years = sample(years, 1))
})
# collapse list back to data frame
map_df <- bind_rows(map_list)
map_df$detection_years <- as.factor(map_df$detection_years)

# Make plot
static_plot <- ggplot(map_df,
                      aes(x = long,
                          y = lat,
                          group = group)) +
   geom_polygon(data = map_df, color = "black", aes(fill = detection_years)) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = terrain.colors(n = length(unique(map_df$detection_years))),
                     name = "Year EAB First Detected") +
   theme_void() +
   coord_fixed(1.3)

animate_plot <- static_plot +
   transition_reveal(detection_years)
```

If it's possible to do this with gganimate, I'd like to but I'm also open to other solutions if anyone has ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After getting an answer from @RLave that almost did what I wanted and spending a little time with the documentation, I was able to figure out a way to do what I want. It doesn't seem very clean, but it works.

Essentially, I created a copy of my data frame for each year that needed a frame in the animation. Then for each year of detection I wanted to animate, I edited the `detection_year` variable in that copy of the data frame so that any county that had a detection in the year of interest or earlier retained their values and any county that had no detection yet was converted to the value I plotted as white. This made sure all the counties were always plotted. Then I needed to use `transition_manual` along with a unique ID I gave to each copy of the original data frame to determine the order of the animation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
# Reproducible example
set.seed(42)
years <- 2002:2006

map_df <- map_data("county") %>% 
   filter(region == "minnesota")

map_df <- map_df %>% 
   group_by(subregion) %>% 
   mutate(detection_year = sample(years,1))

animate_data <- data.frame()
for(i in 2002:2006){
   temp_dat <- map_df %>% 
      mutate(detection_year = as.numeric(as.character(detection_year))) %>% 
      mutate(detection_year = case_when(
         detection_year <= i ~ detection_year,
         detection_year > i ~ 2001
      ),
      animate_id = i - 2001
      )
   animate_data <- bind_rows(animate_data, temp_dat)
}

animate_data$detection_year <- as.factor(as.character(animate_data$detection_year))

# Make plot
static_plot <- ggplot(animate_data,
                      aes(x = long,
                          y = lat,
                          group = group)) +
   geom_polygon(data = animate_data, color = "black", aes(fill = detection_year)) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("white",
                                terrain.colors(n = 5)),
                     name = "Year First Detected") +
   theme_void() +
   coord_fixed(1.3) #+
   facet_wrap(~animate_id)

animate_plot <- static_plot +
   transition_manual(frames = animate_id)
animate_plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Possibily this, but I'm not sure that this is the expected output.

I changed your code, probably you don't need to `split`. I used `group_by` to assign a year to each region.

```
set.seed(42)
years <- 2002:2006

map_df <- map_data("county") %>% 
  filter(region == "minnesota")

map_df <- map_df %>% 
  group_by(subregion) %>% 
  mutate(detection_year = sample(years,1))
```

For the transition you need to define the `id`, here the same as the grouping (`subregion` or `group`) and a correct date format for the transition (`along`) variable (I used `lubridate::year()`)

```
# Make plot
static_plot <- ggplot(map_df,
                      aes(x = long,
                          y = lat,
                          group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", aes(fill = as.factor(detection_year))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = terrain.colors(n = length(unique(map_df$detection_year))),
                    name = "Year EAB First Detected") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_fixed(1.3)

animate_plot <- static_plot +
  transition_reveal(subregion, # same as the group variable
                    lubridate::year(paste0(detection_year, "-01-01"))) # move along years
```

[image]

Does this do it for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm actually not able to get your code to work. It says that it can't find object "detection_year". When I add the data frame source (map_df$detection_year), it tells me the "along" parameter must be an integer, numeric, POSIXct, Date, difftime, or hms. Running just the year(paste0(...)) code alone, it looks like its returning a numeric vector so I'm not sure why I'm getting that error.
Aside from that, this isn't exactly what I was hoping for. I'll clarify in my post above, but I'd like to show all the county polygons as white initially and have each frame fill by year

Comment: @Jake, I just checked and it works smoothly on my part, can you try with a new fresh session? If it still doesn't work maybe update the packages.

Comment: I started a new session and still got the same errors. I updated all my packages and also continue to get the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry about this, can you check the spelling of `detection_year`? in the `transition_reveal` you shouldn't use `map_df$`, just the name of the variable.

Comment: If I copy and paste my answer it works as expected :( If it still won't work, paste here your code, maybe there's some typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189465/discussion-between-rlave-and-jake).

Comment: I was able to get it to work on a different computer. Unsure why it's not working on my current computer.